# Accessing and managing Mule APIs using WSO2 API Management Console?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Is there a way to add APIs/API Proxies developed using Mule to the WSO2 API Management Console to control them and do the same operations as what Anypoint Management Console does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Use your API URL as the backend URL for the APIs you create in WSO2 APIM.

Follow the QSG here.

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/GettingStarted/quick-start-guide/

Comment: I thought your requirement was to get rid of Anypoint layer. (I don't see a point of having 2 API Management layers) If that's true, you should point the API to your real API/service URL (not the proxy URL)

Comment: Yes, sorry that's essentially what I meant.